# Is it possible to find the coordinates of a point in 3D space, given its distance from a known point?

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d

Is it possible to find the coordinates $(x,y,z)$ of a point in $3d$ space when given:

A) the unknown point is $(x,y,z)$.

B) the known point is $(a,b,c)$.

C) the distance between the two points is $D$.

Comment: I really don't know what you wanna say, try to reformulate your question

Comment: A reasonable question, the answer to which happens to be negative.

Comment: Points at distance $D$ from $(a,b,c)$ for a sphere centered at $(a,b,c)$ of radius $D$. Since there are infinitely many of them you can't recover  $(x,y,z)$ uniquely. But it's easy to find some such point.

Answer (score 1):

Since we know $(x,y,z)$ is $D$ away from $(a,b,c)$, if we know what distance we are using, it is computable. Suppose we are using Euclidean distance. Let us for a moment assume $(a,b,c)$ to be on the origin, then $(x,y,z)$ would be a sphere with radius $D$. Imagine you take a point in space, and string of length $D$ attached to it, you make the other end of string move arbitrarily in space (make it tight), then wherever you reach it will be a solution, which in the end forms a sphere.
$$x^2+y^2+z^2 = D^2$$
But then $(a,b,c)$ might not be on the origin, so we shift our picture, resulting
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2 = D^2$$
After a second look it is basically saying that $(D>0)$, the Euclidean distance between these two points is $D$.
$$\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2} = D$$
This equation has infinitely many solutions in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (the 3-D plane in your words), because every point on the sphere would be a solution, and a sphere has infinitely many points on it. So you solution should be
$$\{(x,y,z)\;| \;(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2 = D^2\}$$
The set of all $(x,y,z)$ that satisfies $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2 = D^2$. For example points in this set $(a,b,c+D),(a,b,c-D),(a,b+D,c)$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

A point $(x,y,z)$ could lie anywhere on the sphere whose center is $(a,b,c)$ and whose radius is $D$. So, there is an infinite number of possible solutions. One of them is the point $(a+D, b, c)$. Another is the point $(a, b, c+D)$. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

No.

x, y, and are three unknowns. To find all three of them you would need to set up three equations and then solve the three equations for the three unknowns.

Having the distance to only one point in space will let you set up one of the three equations. Therefore, the distance to only one point in space is not sufficient to find all the unknowns.

You need the distance of you unknown point to (at least) three (other) non-collinear points in the 3D space in order to calculate all three unknowns {x, y, z}.

QED